# How to add TypeHandler when using AS?

Tags: java, mybatis, typehandler

How to add TypeHandler into given `mapper.xml` without resultMap like below.

```
<select id="selectUsers" resultType="User">
select 
uid as "id",
user_name as "userName"
from some_table
where id = #{id}
</select>
```

I want to use some `typeHandler` on `user_name` column.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, no way for your request. I think you should be used  in this case. Why do you not use  ?